# How would I make this type of iOS animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, animation

I have a iOS app that has a menu that slides in. It is something like http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift, except it slides in. I want to make an animation for the menu, in which, the menu rolls down from the top like a carpet unfurling.

Thanks 
Vidur

Comment: See [LottieAnimation](https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/introducing-lottie-4ff4a0afac0e). It's a framework made by AirBnb. It might do what you want. The animation is no longer handled in your code. It's all managed  managed through **Adobe After Effects**. You just read it from a JSON file and then present it.

Answer (score 4):

That's going to be REALLY hard. You'd need to capture the fully displayed view as a bitmap, convert it to an OpenGL texture, and then create a custom OpenGL animation that maps the texture onto a 3D rolling-out-carpet shape.

I've done quite a bit of OpenGL and I wouldn't attempt this unless somebody was paying me by the hour to do it. It would probably take me a week or 2 full time. If you've never done OpenGL, but you understand 3D graphics and transformation matrices, add a month or so to learn OpenGL. If you've never done 3D graphics, add another month of study. If you're not strong in math (trig and algebra, and ideally linear algebra) walk away and forget it.

Comment: is it possible to do it with a open-source library, such as Pop?

Comment: You might be able to do it with GPUImage. I don't know anything about Pop.

Comment: You might want to see [AirBnb'S framework](https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/introducing-lottie-4ff4a0afac0e)

Comment: @Honey Thanks so much !